# PHP Page doesn't load after getting oAuth response from Google for API Access

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

Trying to go through the quickstart guide to get the Google Analytics API working via PHP (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php). While the page loads and jumps over to Google for authorization, the callback page won't load when it comes back from Google: `oauth2callback.php?code=4/xvilrDCNpY6MpFd6cqe2OoWNINiodiZCC0iyX8ZtNtM#`

I just get the following from Chrome and no PHP errors or anything:

> No data received
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/jeremy/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/jeremy/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Comment: The only difference I can see in your implementation is that you have an additional level '/jeremy/' in the url. Do you have the full path of the redirect url in the developer console, and index.php set to http://{yourhostname}/jeremy/oauth2callback.php

Comment: @Matt Yes, it is setup with the subfolder in the developer console and in the index.php file.